# Will reputation on MSO be reflected on SO?

Tags: discussion, reputation

As we can see, in MSO the reputation score and badges are migrated from Stack Overflow statistics of user.

Is this true in both directions?

I mean the reputation I will earn on SO will be reflected on MSO, but what about badges, up votes or down votes reputation of MSO, will this be added/subtracted to the score on SO?

Comment: It's pretty easy to check - I just upvoted your question here and your rep stayed exactly the same (on both SO and MSO), so I guess that answers the question

Comment: Exactly, I got practically implemented answer !! :D

Comment: So, if I get downvoted in the Metarix, I don't die in real life?

Comment: I don't know how it was in 2014, but now badges don't migrated from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You've got it backwards :) Your rep *here* is a reflection of your rep on the parent site. You can earn some badges here independently of the main site (as your badges there don't carry over here), but reputation remains the same across both.

This allows you to have the same moderation privileges that you have on the parent site, Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does that mean that votes on posts here on MSO won't affect reputation at all?

Comment: Is this "status by design" ?

Comment: Reading from now-splitted MSO's "What's Meta", yes it's "status by design"

Comment: But I see the reputation is not synced correctly, on `SO` right now I've `38,943` but on new `MSO` it is still `38,923`, maybe it takes time to update on other site.

Comment: @WereWolf it takes a few minutes or even an hour or so for changes in your main site rep to be reflected on the meta site.

Comment: I can see it now, same on both sites, took approximately `10/12` minutes.

Comment: `This allows you to have the same moderation privileges that you have on the parent site, Stack Overflow.` But I can't see option for reviewing questions(a privilege that I have earned in SO) in MSO.

Comment: @DroidDev, you have less than 2k reputations. There is no review queue for first posts and late answers in meta sites.

Comment: WOOO, that means I have 80k rep on MSO now‽  Awesome! :D

Comment: So this will mean that Jon Skeet will be the top user on MSO. Aaargh!!!

Comment: Does this mean that I shouldn't consider deleting questions that have a substantial net negative score like I would on the main site?

Comment: Did you answer @AndersAbel 's comment? I'm not quite sure if reputation changes here affect my SO rep?

Comment: @Ian - your rep here just mirrors your SO rep, there's no rep to be gained or lost here on meta. You can earn badges here, independent from Stack Overflow, but that's it.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying Tim

Comment: But I do not have the same moderation privileges I have on the main site. If I did, I'd be able to edit posts.