# Voting on MSO - Only for Badges?

Tags: discussion, badges, voting

From this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250078/1104384):

> You've got it backwards :) Your rep here is a reflection of your rep
>   on the parent site. You can earn some badges here independently of the
>   main site (as your badges there don't carry over here), but reputation
>   remains the same across both.
>
> This allows you to have the same moderation privileges that you have
>   on the parent site, Stack Overflow.

There will be no Reputation Gain, So why we need Voting on MSO ? Only for getting Badges ?  I'm afraid that it'll affect the quality of posts in MSO, any thoughts on these ?

Comment: We vote the same way as on any meta: to indicate agreement with a post; and about post quality too.

Comment: "I'm afraid that it'll affect the quality of posts in MSO, any thoughts on these ?" We're all afraid.

Comment: Actually it is much better this way.  a lot less people whining because of the whole "downvotes for disagreement" aspect of meta hurting their rep

Answer (score 5):

It's just **exactly** the same now as on every other site meta. No more rep from retag-requests or asking/answering 'What's wrong with question X'.

This doesn't stop people from using other site metas. Yes, they have significantly less activity, but it's because other main sites got less activity too...