# System check. Downvoting discussions

Tags: discussion, meta, downvotes

There once was a question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250085/voting-on-mso-only-for-badges)

[image: Voting on MSO - Only for Badges?]

It is now a ghost *(due to peer pressure?)* and my question is simple: Is this in any way healthy for the in-universe realm of Stackland?

IMHO this is a typical example for a completely valid meta question. By down-voting signal given is that the topic itself is not welcome. I have to admit that is beyond me. It is not healthy to hide the head in wet cement.

**My question mainly relates to the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) tag.**

The fact that one do not get a rep-hit is good, but still. Is this really the way to welcome discussions contributors to the mother site have?

Is there any remedy for this?

Comment: The fact that a relatively high-rep user did not seem to grasp the meaning and value of votes beyond reputation might well have attracted such votes because of the apparently unresearched or not useful nature. Which would be in line with the tooltips. If so (I can't tell if that's the case), is that a problem?

Comment: @Bart: and the fact that he probably has that much rep for that reason.

Comment: @Bart: Did not think of that. My thought was that even if one do not agree with the indicated premise, the question likely is one that others could have. If it is a problem or not ...? Yes, could be. My initial reaction is that *discussions* should have a very low inn. But I might also have a somewhat skewed perception of the tag.

Comment: Meta is arguably a bit of a strange beast to begin with. But with rep taken out of the equation now, I'd say one of the major pain-points has gone as well.

Comment: So I notice that this question has a close vote, with reason "This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center." Which I agree with. This question is not about Stack Overflow, it's about ***Meta*** Stack Overflow. So where do we ask questions about **Meta Stack Overflow**? On [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)? Or does this mean the close reason text needs to be updated to make ***Meta*** Stack Overflow on-topic for Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Cupcake: On **Meta Meta Stack Overflow.**

Comment: Looks like the question is still up here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250085/voting-on-mso-only-for-badges

Answer (score 3):

It's a misunderstanding of the concept of meta votes, made by cited post author. Twice. Once in the question, second in removing it.

Yes, questions are to be downvoted on meta because they are poor, but such questions should be closed as well. In other (hopefully more common) cases downvoting means disagreeing with either proposal or assumptions made by OP. In cited case it was the assumption, that voting is unimportant once there's no reputation connected with up- and downvotes. The assumption was thought to be wrong by most folks and finally, by the OP himself (why would he delete his own question, if votes aren't important anymore?).