# Is it appropriate to edit a question for grammar / style / formatting?

Tags: discussion, edits

I have previously posted two questions, one to Stack Overflow, and one here, to Meta Stack Overflow.

Both questions have been edited, not because I put up some kind of banned content (although I was told by one of the editors that "Capitals are not optional."). One question was edited, I suppose, because it was too wordy. The other lacked capital letters at the beginning of the sentences (as did this when I wrote it; I assume it will also get edited. I wonder if this comment will survive the cut?) and lacked the high-end formatting that allows things like tags to appear in their little boxes.

So, neither editor answered the question. One even came along after it had been answered.

What is the point of this? Why is it worthwhile to change someone's posts for stylistic reasons? Is this really what is important here?

Comment: Yes, it's customary for users to edit posts that have poor formatting. That's kind of what the purpose of edits are for - to improve the post.

Comment: Do you object to having your question edited? If so, why?

Comment: but isn't that a subjective thing? where does objective improving end, and imposing an opinion about content begin? how can your idea of what my question should contain or should not contain somehow be more appropriate than what i wanted it to contain?

Comment: yes, i object. comment all you want, but it was *my* question. if you change it, isn't it possible that some of the comments or answers become stale?

Comment: The idea is to change the clarity of the message without changing the message.  If your posts have had actual relevant pieces of information edited out, roll it back and flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: See also [Why can people edit my posts?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) in the Help Center, and the FAQ [How does editing work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

Comment: What is subjective about [the English language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_grammar). Ok, some things are but capitalization, for the most part, is not. And why would this bother you so much?

Comment: You can indeed change the question's body completely, but that can be rolled back by anyone else with the editing privilege. In this case, the question still has the same spirit, and the answers still fit pretty well, so it may not be warranted. Sorry you don't like this feature; I sincerely believe that it's one of the best parts of this system.

Comment: I think you have rethink what SO is and what it is not. You are talking about "your" question and you seem offended that someone else edited it. However, this isn't a blog or newspaper, where authors write stuff and others consume this. Think of it more like a wiki - No wikipedian would (or at least _should_) be offended if you editet and improved his/her article.

Comment: Also, I really don't get what you are complaining about? Someone else is spell-checking and correcting your texts? For free! Isn't that awesome? I think the only valid reaction would be a warm "Thank you". Especially because your aversion to capital letters makes your texts terrible to read.

Comment: If you feel so strongly about it being *your* question you always have the option to keep it for yourself. When you post it on SO you'll simply have to accept the fact that it's now part of this site, and subject to editing by the community. If that is not OK for you, that's fine. Simply don't post it here.

Comment: Why so many down votes?  Is this not a valid question?    From the Help section :: "Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing."

Comment: @CramerTV [Voting on meta indicates agreement or disagreement with a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250085/voting-on-mso-only-for-badges#comment347_250085) (and also post quality, but this seems to be secondary).

Comment: Why so many downvotes ? The post looks like a rant but it's still a valid and useful question.

Comment: We only leave text uncapitalized in [*very* unusual circumstances](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton). (See [the final **bb:** paragraph in this interview](http://tug.org/interviews/beeton.html) for an explanation.)

Comment: Why is this downvoted so much? I mean it is a legit question, even though it is a bit neglectful.

Answer (score 75):

You know, every time I see the character "i" in  *any* block of text, I get this sudden urge to go and fix that to be the proper, more regal "I" it deserves to be.

I believe ***strongly*** in improving grammar and formatting - all for the intention of making what one is trying to ask or reply as clear as possible.  I don't do it out of spite (although I weep every time I see an "i"); I do it because it gives the question/answer a better chance of being recognized as a valuable contribution to the community.

And that's what I *really* want to see.

> ... neither editor answered the question. one even came along after it had been answered.

I've done this several times on questions in which I didn't even know a language *existed* for. Thus, I feel that I would be grossly underqualified to have attempted to answer any of those questions.

Besides, editing a question for grammar and clarity can be removed from understanding the technical question being posed, or the code being displayed.  It certainly doesn't *hurt* to have an idea so that the edit doesn't misconstrue the actual content, but they're certainly not mutually required of one another.

Comment: once, i was asked to review the changes that a doc person had made to the tn3270 software documentation. she has spent three weeks on it, and had completely destroyed the document. in cleaning it up, she had fixed all those pesky abbreviations and tortured syntax we had used, making the document unrecognizable to someone who was familiar with how a 3270 terminal worked. it would never occur to me to try and clarify a discussion of something i didn't understand.

Comment: Yet it takes no subject-matter expertise to know that the first letter of each sentence and the word "I" are to be in upper-case.  You seem to have an aversion to the shift key.

Comment: Also, capitalization is the difference between helping your uncle Jack off a horse and helping your uncle jack off a horse.

Comment: "A Woman, without her man, is nothing."   "A woman, without her, man is nothing."  Punctuation is everything! :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice I usually refrain from getting technical, but given the circumstances... A woman;* without her, man is nothing.

Comment: *"You know, every time I see the character "i" in any block of text, I get this sudden urge to go and fix that to be the proper, more regal "I" it deserves to be"* - +1. I wish I could open a bounty and give you more. I despise that freaking cell phone speak. I wish the site would put a filter in place for it.

Answer (score 54):

**What brought you to Stack Overflow in the first place?**

I encourage you to take a moment and think about that question.  Why did you come here?  What made you decide to post a question on our site?  Either you heard people talking about it, and you thought you'd check it out, or you stumbled upon great answers from searches you did that helped you, and then you decided you'd ask a question yourself.

It's not always clear what draws us to a site, until we spend some time there and figure out why it appears at the top of search results and why people talk about it:

***Perhaps it's because the content is clean, neat, and professional looking.***

Editing is perhaps *the* most important feature on Stack Overflow. It's what prevents the Q&A portion of the site from looking like some random snapshot of the Internet, where some harried developer quickly dumps text into a textbox, hoping the people who he is trying to get help from will be able to solve the problem, despite the extra time it takes to parse the question due to sloppiness. *Perhaps this is the very reason you don't go to the forums yourself; there's too much noise to sort through because those communities have no tools to fix posts and make the content look more professional for future visitors.*

Of course, the reason previous posts you may have found on Google were helpful to you was precisely due to the editing features.  You should be happy they exist, as they've unknowingly helped you. At some point, you may have come upon a Stack Overflow post that, at one point, also consisted of sloppy, unprofessional grammar but was fixed by one of our many diligent editors.

The point is that, without editing, we'd either have to require everyone use proper grammar, or we just plain wouldn't be the great resource of professional knowledge that we are today.  I hope you reconsider your plan to move on and instead take the time to understand what makes the Stack Exchange network so great.

Answer (score 23):

While it might be convenient for you to forego using your Shift key, non-standard written English *is* harder to read. If you *really* want to get an answer to your question (or get votes on your answer) you shouldn't purposefully make it harder for your readers.

Besides, collaboratively editing and improving the content of *all* posts is one of the founding principles of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -6):

Personally, I don't mind editing questions to fix egregious spelling an grammar problems.  However, I do find it annoying when people edit them for very minor ones (even when they're not my own ;)

Edits bump questions back up in the queue, and if they are already answered this is really kind of pointless.  We can't stop you from making edits, but please, curb your edit button for minor flaws that add no noticeable improvement to the question/answer, particularly if the question is old or already answered.  Sometimes, you just have to let those little edits go...  This is not Wikipedia.