# Are grammar, spelling and general question tidy-ups contributing to the Stack Overflow community?

Tags: discussion, edits, grammatical-correction

I am on Stack Overflow every day and, to be honest, there are only a few questions I can actually answer. Hence, I am usually on grammar and spelling patrol - to help improve the Stack Overflow community. How much do you think this contributes to the Stack Overflow community? Do you notice it? Has it helped you? Do you regularly edit other people's questions? If so, why do *you* do it?

Comment: As long as you try to address all issues with a post, cleaning up spelling and grammar is *most welcome*!

Comment: +2 reputation for a successful edit (up to a 2k reputation) should tell you that this is encouraged behaviour...cleanliness is nice on a site like this.  Just be careful of too minor edits

Comment: Every site has an option to show the most active [editors of that site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?filter=all&tab=editors) where you can see users have made hundreds of edits. It's certainly encouraged and helps the site.

Comment: See also: [Is it appropriate to edit a question for grammar / style / formatting?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251926/is-it-appropriate-to-edit-a-question-for-grammar-style-formatting)

Comment: People who don't know the difference between *everyday* and *every day* shouldn't be on grammar patrol. ;)

Comment: One thing I worry about is going in and tipping the balance in an odd way. So someone who can't express themselves in English well--but *"I know what they mean"* and step in as a translator who knows both English and programming. Then I disappear because I don't monitor the ensuing conversation where answers start getting incoherent comments in reaction to a question I've cohered to be ordinary. As I haven't monitored (much), I don't know if this leads to future, more severe, misunderstandings.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Improving spelling and grammar makes questions easier to read and quicker to understand. Less time spent trying to understand a question means more time available to answer it. So it's absolutely a good thing.

Comment: Just beware of doing far too little, aka extinguishing the candle but leaving the bonfire. In In that case, I really hope it gets denied as "too minor".

Comment: @Deduplicator, I fail to see how that is detrimental to others or to the text at hand, though. If putting out candles is all you can do, at least it does not hurt.

Comment: Andrew, I'd add that less time understanding the question, or the answer, first and foremost means less time wasted over the man years for people using the QA as reference. If a question takes 4 seconds less on average to understand, and 100 000 people look at it, that is almost three work weeks saved. For a change that maybe took a few minutes.

Comment: @Prof.Falken: it wastes reviewer time. If you can't make a post actually useful, an edit is probably too minor.

Comment: @Wobble, I am sorry, but I fail to see the argument. If the time spent by reviewer is recouped over a decade thousands of times over, how is that still a waste?

Comment: @Prof.Falken If somebody came along and just changed "i" to "I", that could be considered extinguishing a candle. There's literally zero time being recouped by additional understanding from future readers, though; it might be slightly jarring for me to read a lowercase i when it should be an uppercase, but I can still understand (or not, as the case may be) the post just as well.

Comment: Also, it may annoy certain people to have, say, all instances of "it's" converted to "it is". If that is the only thing that gets changed then it is not particularly useful. If I see an edit in the review queue where the only change is some minor spelling I would reject it as too minor.

Comment: Also less error prone I'd say..

Comment: @Prof.Falken: If the question can't be made useful, the benefits won't be experienced over many thousands of views, it will just be deleted.

Answer (score 33):

Yes, improving questions and answers by collaborative editing is on the site's DNA. One of the site founders [announcing Stack Overflow launch](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html):

> There are lots of good ways to edit things. You can improve spelling, grammar, and even copy edit any question or answer to make it better. After all, for the next 20 years, this question will be the canonical place on the web where programmers will come to find out about enlarging fizzbars without overwriting snibbits. Anything you can do to clarify, explain, or improve the question or the answer will be a public service. If there’s code in the answer, you can debug it, refactor it, or tweak it to make it better.
>
> You can also improve on the answers. If an answer is incomplete, expand on it. If an answer has a bug in it or is obsolete, you can edit it and fix it. Because Q&A in Stack Overflow are editable, you can safely link to a Stack Overflow permalink knowing it will always have a good answer. Stack Overflow won’t have the problem of other sites where obsolete or incorrect answers have high Google PageRank simply because they’ve been on the Internet for so long. If someone finds a security bug in an answer, it can be fixed… it won’t keep coming up in Google’s results for years and years poisoning future code.

<sub>PS: Note that the part about refactoring and tweaking an answer's code is not about a regular edit, it can be done but with extreme caution.</sub>

Normally, my edit workflow is:

- Remove tags from title or make its use organic.
- Descriptive title ("Problem with X" => "X does Y in Z circumstances").
- Remove noise ("hello", "thanks", "I'm newbie", "Sorry for engrish", signatures).
- Grammar and spelling.
- Code indentation, if the lack of it makes the code unreadable, and if possible/allowed by the language. Removing *excessive* empty lines may also be warranted. Don't touch anything else on a question's code. Changing coding style is not ok.
- Add or replace tags.
- Use the field "Edit summary" to describe your changes, so the OP and others can learn from it.

Important: read [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) to know the site guidelines about this feature.

Comment: Please, however, be scarce in changing code indentation. Do it really only if the code is unreadable. Changing indentation style is just annoying.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @nico, updated.

Comment: "There are lots of good ways to edit things." Well, a "lot" is a parcel of land or goods. That should read "There are many good ways to edit things." :)

Comment: @DonBranson, the dictionary is telling me both are correct, could this be an issue of UK/USA English?

Comment: Could be. Could also be that the dictionary is not correct and my English teacher was. :) Neither one is perfect.

Comment: OT: In one of the Pratchett books, some tribe (trolls?) does math in terms of "one, two, many, lots". So "lots" is canonical enough usage for me :)

Comment: @Arkadiy, not so OT, before knowing it better, I'd change "colour" for "color". So, if not sure about a word, don't change it ;) Oh, yeah, good to know that *lots* is more than *many*..!

Answer (score 24):

Technical writing commands a high degree of accuracy. The simplest preposition could change the meaning of an entire paragraph, which could then change the entire interpretation of what a program should do. 
Each time I read a well-written question, there's the profile icon of an editor peering right back at me. So yes, I definitely notice it.

Comment: "commands" or "demands"?

Answer (score 16):

I'd like to add that as someone who's had my answers edited, it's helped me learn how to write better questions/answers. It's one thing to see a good question/answer, but it's another to see how your own was changed to make it more readable. The latter is much easier to apply to future questions/answers.

I know there are some people who hate to have their work edited, but there are also many of us who appreciate the efforts of the editors and actually learn from your contributions. We just don't tend to be as vocal about it.

Thank you!

Comment: That's great to hear Rob! It's interesting to hear your opinion, from the other side of the editing.

Comment: Someone needs to edit this post to remove the "Thank you" ;-)

Comment: @Michael: that would definitely be too minor :P

Comment: "Thank you" about what? It's noise on a question, on an answer is doesn't make any sense... Please, check [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/185667)

Comment: @brasofilo "Thank you" to the OP and others who improve the site by editing. Perfectly appropriate in a meta post such as this.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I hear you. I missed the sub-text "Thank you (for doing the internet a better place)". Yes, indeed :)

Answer (score 14):

I must add this is a *must* for those of us who aren't native English speakers.

Many times I wished to thank someone who editing one of my post to fix these kind of issues. This Meta question gave me that opportunity!

Having someone "kind enough" to fix both my grammar and my spelling not only improves the SO experience for those who read my answers/questions, but is also a great help for me in learning how to write <strike>better</strike> "less worse" English.