# Should I have veto power on outside edits to my answers?

Tags: discussion, edits

I know people here strive to give information as accurate and as complete as possible in their answers. I know people modify other people's answers to add details to them, correct them or keep information up to date.

Note: talking primarily about *answers*, not questions. I see a lot more questions getting edits from other users for a lot of reasons which I believe are legit.

However, I had an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502117/program-with-loop-will-not-terminate-with-ctrl-c/25502374#25502374) edited by someone just who erased two words and described the edit as "better English". It's a minor thing, but I asked myself:

What happens if

- edits on answers do more harm than good?
- they do not add, improve or correct anything?
- edits are too minor to make any difference?

in combination with one or more of the following:

- the post is high-quality (complete, correct, detailed, insightful, you name it)
- the one who gives the answer is high-rep (+ maybe high-ego or easily offended as an optional flame ignition bonus)

Should a user (maybe with a higher rep) be trusted with their answers enough to veto an edit suggestion on their own answer? By trust I mean that they are expected to be sensible enough to accept a completion/correction to an answer of theirs if it makes sense.

I also read [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269995/are-grammar-spelling-and-general-question-tidy-ups-contributing-to-the-stack-ov) on grammar and spelling edits, which are often minor.

Comment: You **do** have veto power on *suggested edits*. And you can roll back any applied edits.

Comment: However, we cannot assume that all users are still active, whatever their reputation. We are not going to wait for the author to come back and vote on edits on their posts.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can always roll back or simply undo the changes, but I was referring to some way of rejecting edits altogether

Comment: Because rolling back is just as easy and doesn't require waiting for the author to log in. Which could be never.

Comment: That was an unnecessary edit. Considering you were adding your own emphasis to the text you were quoting that doesn't exist in the original it's actually rather important for those words to stay there. Certainly the removal of two words in a parenthetical comment did not result in "better English". Of course, the real fault lies with the people who approved that edit.

Comment: I do agree that the suggested edit was spurious, useless, and the reviewers that approved that edit should perhaps have someone educate them that that edit should have been rejected instead. Good thing you were active and were able to roll that back, then!

Comment: Perhaps there could be a time threshold. If the author has been active recently, they have to approve suggested edits. But if they haven't been around for a while, edits can be made without their approval, since we're not sure they'll ever come back to do so.

Comment: @Barmar Even if someone was actively recently, we're not sure they'll ever come back. I see what you're saying, but I'm not sure waiting for author approval is really necessary anyway. One of the fundamental points of the site is collaborative editing; poor edits can be (and already are) handled by the community as well as the OP.

Comment: Good point. We normally expect the review process to provide adequate protection against poor edits. It looks like this was just an unfortunate exception, although hardly catastrophic.

Comment: I had an editor "improve" my post three times trying to add mathematically-incorrect code.  At the time, there was a 10-edit threshold to convert to CW so I was somewhat upset at having to roll back and using up four edits out of ten.  However, now that threshold is gone, and I really would not have been upset (but still would have pointed out to the editor that his "improvement" was not mathematically sound).

Comment: Ha ha, "exception".

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a need for a feature change. You were able to roll back the edit, which was exactly the right thing to do in this situation. The post is back in the state it was supposed to be in. Something went wrong, and you had the tools available to correct it. So in that sense, the process worked fine.

Of course the real problem in this case is that somebody made a bad edit, and **it was approved** in the review queue. That's unfortunately quite common, and has been the topic of many lively discussions.