# Why is "Edit Questions And Answers" privilege based on reputation points?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits

Why is the *Editing Questions And Answers* privilege based on reputation points?

The reason I am asking this question is because when someone gains this privilege, he/she also gains the privilege to review suggested edits. Personally, I feel one needs to edit at least 100 questions before getting this privilege. Out of these 100 edits, at least 20-30 should be to rectify spelling and grammatical mistakes.

I am raising this issue because of my experience in the last 3-4 weeks. I edit questions to not only format image, code and links but also to rectify spelling and grammatical mistakes. So, some of my recent edits were just to fix grammatical and spelling mistakes. As per [Edit Questions And Answers Privilege link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), this is mentioned as one of the most important criteria for editing questions. This is also mentioned at: [Importance of spelling and grammar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269995/are-grammar-spelling-and-general-question-tidy-ups-contributing-to-the-stack-ov/270103#270103). Some of my edits were rejected by some members who had privilege to review suggested edits. Fortunately, there were 3 sane reviewers available on that day who differed with the 2 reviewers who thought otherwise. The reason they stated for rejecting my edit is:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

I feel it is stupid to think that correcting spelling and grammatical mistakes does not improve readability. I feel that rectifying spelling and grammatical mistakes improves the post significantly. When I looked at the profiles of such reviewers, I found that even their questions and answers were of similar quality (spelling and grammatical mistakes). So, it was not a surprise that they rejected those suggested edits.
So, some of the suggestions I can think of is:

Review suggested edits privilege should be based on the number of approved edits and not on reputation points. Out of these approved edits, 20-30% of them should be to rectify spelling and grammatical mistakes. Also, I see that some people who have gained 2000 reputation points have never edited even a single question and also have never reviewed even a single *First Post* or *Triage* question.

or

There should be an option in the edit screen to specify that the edit is to rectify spelling and grammatical mistakes. If a reviewer rejects such an edit, he should clearly mention the reason for rejecting such an edit and he should have a valid reason. The question  editor should have an option to challenge such rejected edits (even if only one person rejects the edit).

or

If you still want to reward this privilege on 2000 reputation points, highlight the importance of spelling and grammar when someone gains this privilege. There can be a tutorial that one should read before starting reviewing suggested edits. The user should be allowed to review suggested edits only when he reads the tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

You have had only 5 rejects out of your last 60 edit suggestions.

All 5 were [edit conflicted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286096/what-causes-this-edit-rejection-this-edit-conflicted-with-a-subsequent-edit):

> Someone else edited the question already, and did so in a way that touches the same lines yours does. Its a merge conflict, just like with source control systems.

So these rejections are nothing to worry about.

You effectively have a 100% success record for your last 60 edit suggestions!

Keep up the good work.