# Reputation affected by having an an answer accepted on meta

Tags: discussion, meta

I saw in the [help center question about Meta Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) that votes in MSO do not add to reputation. But it does not talk about reputation earned through having an answer accepted (+15) or through accepting an answer (+2).

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250077/reputation-of-mso-will-be-reflected-on-so) and [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250888/reputation-in-stackoverflow-meta) have vaguely asked if reputation can be earned on MSO and they have been told that upvotes on MSO do not affect SO reputation. But what about reputation through accepting answers/having answers accepted? Is there any way in which reputation is earned on Meta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reputation on per-site metas, including Meta Stack Overflow.

Your reputation is inherited from the main site and is synchronized with it. You do not gain reputation for anything on Meta, because there *is no reputation on Meta*.

[Badges](//meta.stackoverflow.com/badges) are not inherited and must be earned separately here.

[Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com) is its own site with reputation, badges, edits, et cetera, but it is entirely separate from Meta Stack Overflow as of [the split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014) earlier this year.

Comment: Is that the reason why there questions voted so low, even though they are well asked? (maybe I should open question about it)

Comment: @UlysseBN Yes, [voting is different on meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Answer (score 0):

There is no rep on meta at all.

Comment: Short and sweet. I like it.