# Change the description of the Census badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

The [Census](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census) badge description states (emphasis mine):

> Completed the annual Stack Overflow survey and **supplied your profile URL**. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Last year, there was a question in the survey to include your profile URL but now the survey redirects back to Stack Overflow and some internal magic links it all together.

Since there is no way to provide your profile URL, that part should be removed or changed to reflect how it works now.

Comment: Ninja'd by a minute, darn.

Comment: Fun fact: You can tell the survey has been internally live for a little while by seeing this badge was awarded to a couple of employees 2 days ago. So, well done Julia and Brian!

Comment: Personally I would have preferred a warning that the survey would be automatically linked to my profile so I could have decided whether to take it or not.

Comment: @ChrisF agreed - or I could have opted for using incognito

Comment: @Sklivvz Yeah, you can go incognito in your browser, but you would need to know beforehand

Comment: So...is the badge description wrong, or is the survey linked to us by default?

Comment: @Andras The description is wrong (imo) and needs a tweak.

Comment: @ChrisF we don't link it to your profile/user/account/anything else. The tracking GUID is *only* to award the badge and then thrown away. I requested this token be added so the badge wasn't easily exploitable (lowering the value of all badges). It's *not* there for association with your user in any way - that nonce is consumed and then discarded. I think community team is working on a longer answer but I didn't want this definitely unintentional misunderstanding to linger.

Comment: @NickCraver OK, that may be true, but you can now see on my profile that I took this year's survey. That's what I was (perhaps tangentially) referring to. Perhaps I don't want that.

Comment: @ChrisF How is that different from any other badge? We use badges to encourage and recognize positive behaviors and have since Stack Overflow’s inception. We went out of our way to still award a badge without connecting it in data or being able to ever. The badge isn’t new this year.

Comment: FYI Tim gave an official answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361613/unlink-profile-from-2018-developer-survey) to clarify the linking situation (cc @NickCraver)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

We don't associate the profile with your answers. As Nick states in his comment, a GUID is passed to show that you actually completed the survey and it is ephemeral and not stored with your profile or the survey database. We are updating the achievement text to state: "Completed the annual Stack Overflow survey. Your responses are anonymous."

Comment: "Your responses are anonymous" seems like an odd thing to state in a badge description... why not just "Completed the annual Stack Overflow survey"?

Comment: Or "Completed the anonymous annual Stack Overflow survey"

Comment: Or "Completed the annual Stack Overflow survey anonymously"?

Comment: Or "Anonymously completed the annual Stack Overflow survey" or "Completed the annual Stack Overflow survey, anonymously you have" ...

Comment: or, "Completed anonymously the annual Stack Overflow survey"?

Comment: or, "_<Enter description here>_"

Comment: Saying *"Completed anonymously"* implies there is another way and another badge..

Comment: i'm new here. How does Joe only have 101 points? this answer itself has 27+ up votes (i.e atleast 270) points? What am i missing? Are there no points on meta?

Comment: @Vinay, yes, anything on meta [does not affect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250078) your Stack Overflow reputation.

Comment: You've missed my point about not wanting it to be public knowledge that I've filled out the survey. In previous years I've not filled out my profile URL, but this year I didn't get the choice.

Comment: @ChrisF You could take the survey when you're logged out. I understand it's too late this year, but you can try to remember that next year.

Comment: @DonaldDuck - it's that "try to remember" bit ;)