# Unlink profile from 2018 Developer Survey

Tags: support, survey-2018

I took the 2018 Developer Survey and was surprised when upon completion I was awarded with a Census badge automatically. In previous years this only happened if you manually entered your Stack Overflow profile, which I would choose not to do.

I understand I could have (and probably should have) used an incognito window to fill out the survey to prevent this, but I have taken the survey in previous years and it has never been linked to my profile automatically before, so this behaviour really broke my expectations.

Is there any way to unlink my profile from the survey I submitted? I was relatively open with information under the assumption that it was totally anonymous; knowing that it is linked to my profile makes me uncomfortable.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The *event* of completing the survey is linked to your profile, what you put there isn't - this is why we couldn't automate awarding the badge only if you put in your profile link. The presence of the badge itself only indicates that you completed the survey; it doesn't provide a bridge of any kind. The data is anonymous in the absence of you manually providing a profile link.

This was [mentioned on Twitter](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/950408869079060480) as well. It just automates the badge so we don't have to (sometimes erroneously) do it manually. If you want it removed, contact us privately and let us know.

Nothing to worry about :)

***Update for clarity:***

When you return from the survey, a special GUID lets the system know that something called a user history event needs to be created, and something like `UserCompletedSurvey` is stored within that created row. The presence of this event is what causes you to earn the badge.

**No correlating information (e.g. that GUID) is stored, the only data that we record is that the event happened.** Put more simply, if someone told us that the only way we could save [Jay Hanlon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/347414/jaydles?tab=profile) from [the evil Skeletor](http://he-man.wikia.com/wiki/Skeletor) was to reveal the information that Jay provided in the survey, well, we couldn't save him. The only bridge between Jay and the information he provided was burned once we failed to record anything except for the fact that he successfully exited the survey.

We'll be updating the badge description to indicate that it's awarded if you take the developer survey *while logged in*  to clear up any ambiguity that we can *now*, and consult with our corporate counsel regarding any other specific language that we might be able to put in other places to ease concerns of folks that are accustomed to thinking of privacy concerns from a European perspective.

This isn't the only badge that gets awarded based on your behavior while logged in (and contingent upon that, think of the Fanatic badge), but we want to make sure folks are delighted and not abruptly surprised by earning it (and others), so we'll have them take a pass at it.

Thanks, everyone, for pointing this out.

Comment: It's still a little disconcerting to take the survey and not have a warning _in survey_ of this... Granted, I don't mind because I trust the team to protect what I tell them, but the survey should have a huge bold warning at the start, or at the top of every page...

Comment: @Kendra Heard, a few people indicated that they found this jolting and I'm passing it on to the survey team now.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks, that makes me feel a lot better. Has this changed from last year where there was a link or am I misunderstanding your comment [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341214/introducing-the-silver-census-badge#comment430378_341214)?

Comment: @PixelElephant It has changed (which I just realized). I haven't taken the survey since I stopped programming and the last draft version of this year's I saw did have the field (to my recollection), but I could be wrong - must have changed later. In any event, it doesn't influence my answer, we don't link it automatically (and apparently, no longer elective manually either, if the field to add it is missing).

Comment: Just marks one of those moments where working in a pretty big company still feels like a small company except for those _few_ moments where you're like "I can't believe I didn't know that". Anyway, I pinged all the people and let them know.

Comment: I think it's a bit more complex than we make it. You store data which is PII when linked together. You have a possible way of linking the data (the GUID token passed between the survey and the site). You *are* therefore handling new PII which requires by law a series of guarantees, the right to forget, identifying who is responsible for the data, indicating how long you retain the data for, etc. In this case, if you forget the PII link straight away, then you should (officially) declare in the terms of service that you have this zero day retention policy. It is not sufficient IMO, to say it

Comment: in a random tweet or post. Keep in mind that the EU is *brutal* about defending privacy and that the fines are enormous and measured as a fixed percentage of your turnaround. Consult a lawyer, because it really looks like you are in breach. IANAL.

Comment: @Sklivvz I'm fairly confident that all of that relates to the [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation), which isn't enforceable until May.

Comment: @TemporalWolf no: most of these provisions are in the current version of the law.

Comment: I've updated the answer, thanks everyone! We'll do a few things now to make sure people's expectations are correctly set, and have our corporate counsel do a more thorough review of this (and similar) badges to make sure we're in a good position from a global perspective.

Comment: Here's a bit of context as to why we made the change. Last year, we had a manual process, where users had the option to submit their profile URL and then we manually awarded the badges on the back end. It was rife with issues, especially if someone was not a member of Stack Overflow itself, but was a member of a different Stack Exchange community. We implemented the automatic Census badge to minimize the hassle some users experienced last year in getting their badges. Sorry if we didn't communicate this well and it caused PII alarm bells to go off unnecessarily. Our intentions were good.