# The survey's public data dump should have a random order

Tags: discussion, privacy, survey-2018

This is a follow up question to [Unlink profile from 2018 Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361613/7586)

The claim in the answer is that only a GUID connects the survey result to the user profile, and that GUID is not recorded.

It goes even further and claims:

> if someone told us that the only way we could save Jay Hanlon from the evil Skeletor was to reveal the information that Jay provided in the survey, well, we couldn't save him. The only bridge between Jay and the information he provided was burned once we failed to record anything except for the fact that he successfully exited the survey.

Well, I certainly hope my colleagues will show more resolve than that when I'm stuck in a parallel universe, being tortured by a body-building skeleton.

Jay as received [his Census badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census?userid=347414) at **2018-01-08 19:26:49Z**. He must have completed the survey a few seconds before. This information is enough to narrow down the possible responses to a few dozens at most - even before considering public knowledge like country, education, or company size.

Further, currently about 26,000 users have received the [Census badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census) for the 2018 survey (436 pages, 60 per page), and **we know order at which they received it**. For example, we know [Brian Nickel](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census?userid=860000) and [Julia Silge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census?userid=5468471) have completed the survey before it was published, and they would have two of the first responses.

Given this information, I think it is clear the public results should not include a timestamp (previous results did not include it anyway).
The [2017 survey result CSV](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2017&utm_content=blog-link&utm_term=data) did contain the column `Respondent`, with an ID from 1 to 51,392. If this is the real order, again, we could have a problem.

So, a minor conclusion - please remember randomizing the row order before publishing the results.

Comment: This question started as a comment but got out of hand.

Comment: So you're saying you want to take away Jay's last chance to be saved from Skeletor.

Comment: Badges are not awarded immediately.  The window of time that the survey could have been submitted in, given the badge time, is going to be several minutes.  Possibly there were no other submission in that whole time, but plausably not.

Comment: @Servy fair, but the argument for randomizing the results and removing time stamps still seems really strong.

Comment: @Servy - For me it was awarded immediately. If you look at the [Census](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census), the resolution for this badge is by the second, not once every few minutes.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - It is too often that the threat of terror is presented as the excuse for limiting privacy. More seriously, the SO staff can have access to the timestamps (like they have access to profile links in previous surveys), so they can save employees from skeletors. That just makes sense. Further, I urge both sides to reach a peaceful solution.

Comment: Indeed. And maybe... maybe Skeletor isn't that bad an employee after all. As we all know, you can't trust the press these days, and I'm sure he could use a VP of Community Growth. The torture thing could be taken care of in a reasonable employment contract.

Comment: I had the same fear about deanonymisation as you - especially given that the survey invites people in some jurisdictions to [admit to capital offences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_penalty_for_homosexuality) - and had also noticed that the Census badge is not awarded in batches and has already been issued tens of thousands of times. I was about to post essentially this post, and I'm glad to see that somebody got there before me.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is a great comment; thanks for the detailed thoughts. We have always removed timestamps (at least since I have been involved), done work to replace very high outliers on salary with values like `">$400,000"`, and taken similar steps to reduce how easy it is to identify people from their survey responses.

In looking through last years' analysis scripts, it appears we did randomize `Respondent` so that it is a random ID, not the order in which the respondents took the survey. We will be sure to take this privacy step again this year.

Comment: Is the order of everything else randomized? Because it makes little sense to randomize the field while keeping everything else in a neat order.

Comment: @Braiam I don't think I understand your comment. It absolutely would not make sense to scramble which answers belong to which respondent IDs; this would render the dataset meaningless noise.

Comment: What I said was that if the observations (rows) are still in order, it would be quite trivial to figure out who answered what, since the row order could be used to identify respondents. I expect that the released dataset would not have you and Brian at the first 2 rows, wouldn't we?

Comment: @Braiam - The CSV of 2017 is ordered by the column `Respondent`, which is confirmed to be randomized, so we're good there.

Comment: AOL did something similar in 2006 (fueled by great intentions!)

Answer (score 31):

If you are concerned about your privacy, I don't think this randomisation alone is enough to ensure it, due to the rather small size of the dataset. It is fairly easy to filter someone out with a little publicly available information.

Taking you and last year's survey as an example (I assume you filled in the survey in 2017):

For 2017 there were only 575 respondents from Israel (where you state in your profile you live), of which 14 have worked with .Net and AWS (your technologies from your Stack Overflow profile). You also name the company you work for, so by taking into account their size, I brought it down to one entry.

Of course this still assumes you filled in the survey last year, you don't lie in your profile etc.

And again I am not claiming I am sure that I found your entry, I just want to point out that with this little data, it is very easy to filter. If you are concerned about your privacy, the safer option is to remove personal data from your public profile(s).

Comment: This is absolutely true as well. We reduce how easy it is to identify people by not sharing, for example, which state people say they live in within the United States or province in Canada, any identifications about disability, etc, but this is not a guarantee by any means. I especially worry about individuals who identify with rare sexual orientations (very, very few respondents identify as gay or transgender) and small countries, like this example.

Comment: Marvelous! Luckily for me, I'm aware enough and I fill the data pretty much as if it was in public. I try not to include anything I don't want to share. In general, when I enter data like "Israel", it is clear to me that narrows down the options significantly. I can say that I did the same exercise as you on the 2017 survey before posting this question, and I couldn't find myself! (but I did narrow it down to a few rows)

Comment: Oh, time to ask your colleagues to complete the StackOverflow survey to make your own data more private!

Comment: Security by obscurity is **never** the solution though :).

Comment: Even if your personal data isn't in your profile, it's definitely available to a committed enough adversary (or just somebody who knows you well).

Comment: @Roberrrt actually, it's by aggregation that privacy is kept. There's no sure fire method that you can't narrow down respondents if you know enough information, but you can statistically speaking make it more difficult.